# find the minimal positive eigenvalue satisfying (A+tB)v=0

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, positive-semidefinite

Given conditions:

1. matrix $A$ is symmetric and positive definite
2. matrix $B$ is symmetric and NOT positive definite
3. $0\leq t$

then linear system
$$(A+tB)x=y$$

has solution for $0\leq t<\bar t$, where $\bar t$ represents the the minimal positive eigenvalue of the problem:
$$ (A+tB)v=0  $$

How to calcuate the value of  $ \bar t$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking but presumably you can determine the relevant values of $t$ from the fact that $A+tB = A (I + t A^{-1}B)$, so $\det (A+tB) = \det A \det (I + t A^{-1}B)$?

Comment: thank copper.hat, so do you suggest $ t= -1/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is eigenvalues of $A^{-1}G$?